# create new column based on existing column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an excel file that has 2 columns 'Food' and 'Flavor'. I want to create a new column 'Flavors' based on the existing columns, where the flavors are aggregated for each food group and separated by a whitespace.

See below:

| Food | Flavor | Flavors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Cranberry | Cranberry Peach Lemon |
|  | Peach |  |
|  | Lemon |  |
| Banana | Chocolate | Chocolate Peanut Vanilla |
|  | Peanut |  |
|  | Vanilla |  |

Above is what Ide like to be the final output.

How could I do this in python?

This is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx')
```

Yep thats it! Unfortunately.

I feel so stuck, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is exactly as written, with NaN values in empty cells, you can first use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill in the null values in the `Food` column, then use an aggregation followed by a [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html?highlight=transform#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform) :

```py
df = df.ffill()
df["Flavors"] = df.groupby("Food").transform(" ".join)
```

This gives the following result :

```
     Food     Flavor                   Flavors
0   Apple  Cranberry     Cranberry Peach Lemon
1   Apple      Peach     Cranberry Peach Lemon
2   Apple      Lemon     Cranberry Peach Lemon
3  Banana  Chocolate  Chocolate Peanut Vanilla
4  Banana     Peanut  Chocolate Peanut Vanilla
5  Banana    Vanilla  Chocolate Peanut Vanilla
```

If for some reason you want to keep the null values, you can use :

```py
df["Flavors"] = df.ffill().groupby("Food").transform(" ".join).drop_duplicates()
```

That will return :

```
     Food     Flavor                   Flavors
0   Apple  Cranberry     Cranberry Peach Lemon
1     NaN      Peach                       NaN
2     NaN      Lemon                       NaN
3  Banana  Chocolate  Chocolate Peanut Vanilla
4     NaN     Peanut                       NaN
5     NaN    Vanilla                       NaN
```